# The value of variable displayed as null instead of formatted date

Tags: jasper-reports

Hello I'm having issues displaying a string date of this format `"01-Nov-16"` as `"01-11-2016"` `null` is what's returned. I have tried all I know. Below is my exact xml.

```
<variable name="S_DATE" class="java.util.Date">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy",java.util.Locale.US).parse($P{startdate})]]></variableExpression>
</variable>

<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" isBlankWhenNull="false">
    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="205" y="0" width="102" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" forecolor="#000000" uuid="560349d8-0bb8-44f0-90ce-41ffb71544cc"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Left">
        <font size="10"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{S_DATE}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

The type of `startdate` parameter is `String`

Comment: @Winnie What is type of `$P{startdate}`? What value did you check?

Comment: @AlexK its a string eg. "01-Nov-16"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First approach

Try to use parameter instead of variable. No need to use the "power" and features of variables in this case.

#### Sample

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Format date" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <parameter name="dateAsString" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["01-Nov-2016"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="dateParam" class="java.util.Date">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy", Locale.US).parse($P{dateAsString})]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField pattern="dd-MM-yyyy">
                <reportElement x="130" y="20" width="250" height="30"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{dateParam}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

#### Output result

The result in *Jaspersoft Studio* will be:

[image]

### Second approach

Change the `resetType` of the variable. The valid type for your case will be ***None***. The right expression will be:

```
<variable name="S_DATE" class="java.util.Date" resetType="None">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy", Locale.US).parse($P{startdate})]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

Comment: I had the same issue. Setting the "resetType" to "None" solved it. Thanks!